# Can I use glib to make some portable http GET request and how?

Tags: http, cross-platform, webrequest, glib

Was just wondering if any of you already coded a http get request using glib?
Is it possible and how ?

I just want to call an simple urls with parameters, and the code must be working on gnu/linux, windows and mac.

If it is not possible with glib, have you any suggestion about what to use for that purpose (in a portable perspective).
I want to avoid if possible 3rd party libs to minimize my project dependencies. So in that case of glib is not the right way, any code fragment will be welcome !

Thanks
Sinn'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [libsoup](http://live.gnome.org/LibSoup).  It's part of GNOME, and designed for use with GLib.  You can start with the [howto](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libsoup/stable/libsoup-client-howto.html).  E.g. it shows how to create a basic GET request:

```
SoupMessage *msg;
msg = soup_message_new ("GET", "http://example.com/");
SoupSession *session = soup_session_sync_new();
guint status = soup_session_send_message (session, msg);
```

Comment: +1 but it would be more help if you also showed the creation of a soup session .  `SoupSession *session = soup_session_sync_new();`